# Spring Data JPA: findAllByOrderBy does not sort

Tags: java, mysql, sorting, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my SpringBoot service, I want to get all 'person' entities from my mysql database, primarily sorted by value 'month', secondarily sorted by value 'day'.

A list with all entities is returned, but their order is the one in which they were added to the database, independently from the attributes 'month' and 'day'.

What am I doing wrong?

Repository:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, UUID> {
    public List<Person> findAllByOrderByMonthAscDayAsc();
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    @JsonIgnore
    private UUID id;

    @Column
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private Integer month;

    @Column
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private Integer day;

    public Person(){
    }

    public Integer getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(Integer month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public Integer getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(Integer day) {
        this.day = day;
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class BdayService {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    public BdayService(){
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Person> findAllSorted(){
        List<Person> persons = personRepository.findAllByOrderByMonthAscDayAsc();
        return persons;
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't worked enough with Boot and JPA to give a full answer, but I can tell that the order by clause you are invoking is not being executed.

Comment: Add `spring.jpa.show-sql = true` in application.properties. Now, execute this query. You will now be able to the SQL Query in the Application Logger. Can you print the query here?

Comment: After adding spring.jpa.show-sql = true in the properties, the logger shows: Hibernate: select person0_.id as id1_1_, person0_.creation_timestamp as creation2_1_, person0_.day as day3_1_, person0_.forename as forename4_1_, person0_.month as month5_1_, person0_.surname as surname6_1_, person0_.update_timestamp as update_t7_1_, person0_.year as year8_1_ from person person0_

Comment: I did exactly the same what you did and I see select person0_.id as id1_1_, person0_.day as day2_1_, person0_.month as month3_1_ from person person0_ order by person0_.month asc, person0_.day asc ! So it's working. what versions are you using

Comment: spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.0.1.RELEASE with managed version 5.1.46 for mysql-connector-java

Comment: switching to 2.0.4.RELEASE did not solve the problem

Comment: Version of the mysql server is: 5.7.21-log

Comment: The code is correct and the problem is only me. I made requests to the wrong path. The controller listening there did exactly what it was supposed to do, i.e. delivering all entities unsorted. Making requests to the controller executing the findAllByOrderByMonthAscDayAsc() method did solve the problem. Thanks for your time...